# Mismatch between the data received from POSTMAN compared to JAVA rest api call

Tags: java, rest, postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JahP.png)Hi Team,

When I am trying to pull the records from salesforce database by an API call I'm getting a response differently compared to when I make the call in postman for a order. I am not getting any errors but the java rest api call response is not getting the same response as I was expecting from the salesforce output.
I tried switching the browser clearing the cache and that didn't work.
From Java rest api call I see two records obtained but when I did with salesforce I can see one (P.S I used the same url and copied the same token from java rest get call)

Comment: provide more information. instead of uploading a screenshot, text would have been more useful.

Comment: I have pasted a screenshot but it is not allowing me to do as there is some requirement of number posts that are needed to attach any pictures.

Comment: no need to include screenshot, you can update question to include post man response by removing confidential information in the response,

Answer (score 0):

can you please check whether you are hitting with the same user/ same user bearer token.

some times the data will be fetched based on the groups maintained in the application, in that case also you can see the difference in the output.

Check in your code whether you are maintaining any groups.

Comment: it seems he is using same token, mentioned it in question

Comment: Also check if you are using the same request headers.